# querying using != against a field that has some NULL values

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have report that references a view in a SQL Server.  The user can filter on a char field, but when they filter using "!=" to a value it filters out those records with that value AND any records that have a NULL value in that field.  I tested this outside of the report, by putting the filter in the WHERE clause of SQL code and got the same results. Why is this happening?  How can I get around this issue?

For instance:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM aTable

 f1   f2   f3
---- ---- ----
 Y    Y    NULL
 Y    N    M
 N    Y    N
 Y    N    NULL

SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM aTable
WHERE f3 != 'N'

 f1   f2   f3
---- ---- ----
 Y    N    M
```

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Any insight you can provide would be helpful :-)

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparison operations with NULL always evaluate to false. You can use:

```
WHERE f3 is null or f3 != 'N'
```

Comment: I had though ORing for NULL, but since this is a report (which is in a propitiatory system) that the use can filter on, or not, on this field this will not  work :-(  The report system does have "Pre-process" field for doing things like this, but it is shotty as best and usually causes other issues when used... so long shorty short, I don't want to explore that as a solution.  

Is there any other way to get around this?

Comment: You could use a different value than NULL, such as an empty string, to represent "no data" in column `f3`.

Comment: Thank you Greg, but I can't do that either :-(  I have no control over the data in the DB, and when a new record is created from the app this field has a NULL value.  Thanks again for trying to help me with this! :-)  I am guess there isn't anything I can do :'-(

Comment: If you can change the database schema, you might be able to set a default value on the `f3` column so that if that column isn't mentioned in an INSERT, it gets the default value. Not sure of the exact behaviour if NULL is specifically mentioned in the INSERT statement, though.

Comment: That is a great idea!  I do have access to a "test" version of the DB.  I will see if I can do that there.  Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL function

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM aTable WHERE ISNULL(f3,'')!='N'
```